# Update all Dictionary (from JSON) values recursively

Tags: python

In order to automatically make an interface for a Typescript project I made the following code that changes all the non dictionary values of a dictionary (parsed from JSON file) to it's types:

```
import os
import json

interface = 'export interface NewInterface {\n'

with open('dummy.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    string = file.read()
    jsonData = json.loads(string)
    #working code for up to 3 levels
    for key1, value1 in jsonData.items():
        if isinstance(value1, dict):
            interface = interface + f'\t{key1}: ' + '{\n'
            for key2, value2 in value1.items():
                if isinstance(value2, dict):
                    interface = interface + f'\t\t{key2}: ' + '{\n'
                    for key3, value3 in value2.items():
                        if isinstance(value3, dict):
                            interface = interface + f'\t\t{key3}: ' + '{\n'
                        elif (isinstance(value3, int) or isinstance(value3, float)):
                            interface = interface + f'\t\t\t{key3}: number;\n'
                        else: 
                            interface = interface + f'\t\t\t{key3}: string;\n'
                    interface = interface + '\t\t},\n'
                elif (isinstance(value2, int) or isinstance(value2, float)):
                    interface = interface + f'\t\t{key2}: number;\n'
                else:
                    interface = interface + f'\t\t{key2}: string;\n'
            interface = interface + '\t},\n'
        elif (isinstance(value1, int) or isinstance(value1, float)):
            interface = interface + f'\t\t{key1}: number;\n'
        else:
            interface = interface + f'\t{key1}: string;\n'
    interface = interface + '}\n'

print(interface)
```

With a proper interface generated I am able to make the following typescript file (will also be automated, but I removed this part to make the question shorter):

```
export interface NewInterface {
    keyOne: {
        lorem: string;
        title: string;
    },
    keyTwo: {
        category: string;
        id: number;
        title: string;
        secondId: number;
    },
    keyThree: {
        title: string;
        subtitles: {
            tOne: string;
            tTwo: string;
            tThree: string;
        },
        parOne: string;
        parTwo: string;
        parThree: string;
    },
}
```

The problem is that the following code only works for 3 levels of nested dictionaries, but what if I have 10 levels?
Therefore, I'm trying to make in a recursive way and I can't figure out how. Any help is much appreciated.
Tabs are optional.

For reference the original .json file:

```
{
    "keyOne": {
        "lorem": "ipsum",
        "title": "people"
    },
    "keyTwo": {
        "category": "smartphones",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "She has seen this scene before",
        "secondId": 32
    },
    "keyThree": {
        "title": "body",
        "subtitles": {
            "tOne": "One 1",
            "tTwo": "Two 2",
            "tThree": "Three 3"
        },
        "parOne": "Here 1",
        "parTwo": "Here 2",
        "parThree": "Here 3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is in .py, not .ts, *don't abuse tags please*

Comment: Thanks, I'm still finding out how tags work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call recursively:

```
interface = 'export interface NewInterface {\n'
def generate_interface(s, data, depth = 1):
    indentation = '\t'*depth
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            s = generate_interface(s + indentation + f'{k}: ' + '{\n',
                                   v, depth + 1)
        elif isinstance(v, (int, float)):
            s += indentation + f'{k}: number;\n'
        else:
            s += indentation + f'{k}: string;\n'
    return s + '\t'*(depth-1) + '},\n'

with open('dummy.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    string = file.read()
    jsonData = json.loads(string)
    print(generate_interface(interface, jsonData)[:-2])
```

Answer (score 2):

just a quick and dirty implementation, but it should get you started:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

json_data="""
{
    "keyOne": {
        "lorem": "ipsum",
        "title": "people"
    },
    "keyTwo": {
        "category": "smartphones",
        "id": 1,
        "title": "She has seen this scene before",
        "secondId": 32
    },
    "keyThree": {
        "title": "body",
        "subtitles": {
            "tOne": "One 1",
            "tTwo": "Two 2",
            "tThree": "Three 3"
        },
        "parOne": "Here 1",
        "parTwo": "Here 2",
        "parThree": "Here 3"
    }
}
"""

import json

data = json.loads(json_data)

def dict_to_interface ( d, depth = 0 ):
    res = []
    spaces = "    " * depth
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance ( v, dict ):
            res.append ( '%s%s: {\n%s\n%s}' % ( spaces, k, dict_to_interface ( v, depth + 1 ), spaces ) )
        else:
            type = 'string'
            if isinstance ( v, int ): type = 'number'
            elif isinstance ( v, bool ): type = 'boolean'
            elif isinstance ( v, list ): type = 'string[]'

            res.append ( "%s%s: %s;" % (spaces, k, type ) )

    return '\n'.join ( res )


print ( "export interface NewInterface {\n%s\n}" % dict_to_interface ( data, 1 ) )
```

Comment: This will work; the commas are wrong, where it should be semicolon, but *that's fine*. Prettier will auto replace comma with semicolon, and the code with the interface will be perfectly valid. **However**, you're missing the top line in the output `export interface <Name> {`. Without that, Prettier won't format the code and make it valid.

Comment: Thank you, for a quick and dirty implementation is more than enough to get me started.

Comment: @rv.kvetch you are right. I am sorry, I didn't check the original post for the right format. Since I am not a TypeScript user, I didn't noticed the semicolon. My fault ;-)

Comment: @Fabio no problem, we all make mistakes. I am saying that rest of it is fine, and only the part at the start is needed. Once you update to add the start line as mentioned, I see no reason why this doesn’t deserve an upvote.

Comment: Hello @rv.kvetch  and thank you for your feedback. I have updated the code accordingly.